# Rename multiindex headers in one column only

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to change the subcolumn headers of a multiindex dataframe.  The trick is that I'm only trying to change the headers under one of the supercolumns.  See below

**Given:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [10,20,30,40], [100,200,300,400]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("a", "b"), ("a", "c"), ("d", "b"), ("d", "c")))
```

I want to change the column header `b` to `j` BUT ONLY under column `a`; I want the headers under column `d` to remain unchanged.

If I wanted all columns `b` to be changed I'd do the following

`df.rename(columns={'b': 'j'}, level=1)`

How can I specifiy the super column under which to change the subcolumn headings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `map` over column names and check if the index is `('a', 'b')` and replace `b` with `j` if it matches:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: ('a', 'j') if x == ('a', 'b') else x)

df    
#     a         d     
#     j    c    b    c
#0    1    2    3    4
#1   10   20   30   40
#2  100  200  300  400
```

Comment: This one is the better solution. Instead of flattening the columns to  list of tuples and then change the values and convert it back to multi level columns , Map will do a great job +1.

Comment: @Pygirl thanks. +1 for you too. Your solution is a good one as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: (not so good but works)

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x,'j') if (x=='a' and y=='b') else (x,y) for x,y in df.columns])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [10,20,30,40], [100,200,300,400]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("a", "b"), ("a", "c"), ("d", "b"), ("d", "c")))
print(df)
     a         d     
     b    c    b    c
0    1    2    3    4
1   10   20   30   40
2  100  200  300  400
```

Now rename the columns:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((("a", "j"), ("a", "c"), ("d", "b"), ("d", "c")))
print(df)
     a         d     
     j    c    b    c
0    1    2    3    4
1   10   20   30   40
2  100  200  300  400
```

Comment: Technically, that would do it but it assumes that I know the order in which the columns are arranged which is an assumption I would like to avoid.